Building a GRE tunnel with netplan
Couldn't find a complete working example of this on the whole wide Internet. This question is similar to Use working GRE tunnel as default on remote server but using netplan instead of ip commands. In fact, using ip commands works for me, so there are no router issues between the servers. However, I need it to be done the netplan way:
Scenario:

Both servers on Ubunutu 22.04
"HUB" machine (hosting a webserver): 23.20.20.10
"SPOKE" machine (has the "public-facing" IP):

Main IP: 109.99.99.82
Secondary IP: 109.99.99.96



(All IPs are merely examples.)
Goal:
The goal is to access SPOKE's secondary IP from the outside world, but really get the webpage served from the HUB machine:
So curl http://109.99.99.96 will serve a page that really comes from 23.20.20.10.
Likewise, when in a shell on HUB, executing curl --interface 109.99.99.96 icanhazip.com the expected output will be 109.99.99.96 even though the command was issued from HUB whose real IP is 23.20.20.10.
For the answer to be accepted, the tunnel must work in both directions.
On SPOKE, the /etc/netplan/SPOKE.yaml file currently looks as follows:
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
      - 109.99.99.82/24   # Local main IP on SPOKE
      - 109.99.99.96      # Local secondary IP on SPOKE
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 109.99.99.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
  tunnels:
    gre1:
      mode: gre
      local: 109.99.99.82       # Local main IP on SPOKE
      remote: 23.20.20.10       # Remote main IP on HUB
      addresses:
        - 109.99.99.96/24       # Tunnel IP from SPOKE to HUB
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2


On HUB, the /etc/netplan/HUB.yaml file currently looks as follows:
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0:
      addresses:
      - 23.20.20.10/29
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 23.20.20.1
  version: 2


My question:
Please correct the configuration for the tunnel to work in both directions! As it is shown here, the configuration does absolutely nothing, in either direction.
SPOKE.yaml was created reading the docs and some "kinda similar" examples online.
HUB.yaml is the factory default, I have no idea what to put there.
Please help, I have not been able to find even ONE working example of a complete bidirectional GRE tunnel made with netplan online!
Thanks! ❤️

Have you not tried adding a symmetrical tunnels: section to HUB.yaml? The necessary configuration for 'curl' to work that way involves a bit more than just the tunnel, but you're asking for a lot if you're expecting a 100% finished configuration as the answer without putting in any effort yourself.

@grawity where does it say I didn't put in any effort myself? The tunnel doesn't even work in one direction, so adding the same to the HUB in the other direction leads to the same result (none). Also, if you had ever set up a GRE tunnel before (with ip commands), you'd know that the configuration is NOT the exact same on both ends. So I don't understand the point of your comment. You don't seem to know how to do it either, but feel compelled to wag the finger and make assumptions about my effort? Do you have any constructive ideas to contribute instead?

They are symmetric on both ends. The point of my comment was that tunnels will never work with only one side, until both ends are configured – it's never enough for one side to send traffic; the other side has to expect to receive it – otherwise you're sending packets into the void; "doesn't even work with one direction" is very much like expecting a battery or a light bulb to work with only one wire connected. (That's half of it; the other half is that TCP connections also are inherently bidirectional, and it's impossible to make a connection when packets only go in one direction.)

So this is a place to get shamed for asking a question, and get berated by people who don't know the solution either? You have contributed exactly zero to the solution here; you're just lecturing some theoretical concepts. IDK what the point of your sermon is, other than that you're trying to get some emotional regulation out of it. Do you have any actual netplan configurations tips for us?


Please correct the configuration for the tunnel to work in both directions! As it is shown here, the configuration does absolutely nothing, in either direction.

For a tunnel to work in both directions or even in one direction, it has to be configured on both ends. Otherwise you are only sending packets into the void, as machine A sends packets that machine B does not expect to receive, much like trying to connect via HTTP to a system that has no HTTP server.
The same also applies for a different reason: TCP connections such as those made by 'curl' inherently require bidirectional communication. So it's not enough for Hub to receive and unpack the tunneled packets; it has to tunnel the "reply" packets the same way back to Spoke.
Altogether it means that tunneling TCP over GRE is generally "all or nothing" – the tunnel doesn't really start working incrementally in one direction; it should be expected that it remains nonfunctional until both sides are set up.

you'd know that the configuration is NOT the exact same on both ends

The configuration of the tunnel is symmetric on both ends: the same tunnels: section with local: ⇆ remote: addresses swapped, and with the tunnel interface's IP addresses chosen like you would for a physical cable (e.g. 192.168.0.1/24 ⇆ 192.168.0.2/24 respectively). The latter should be chosen so that they don't overlap with physical interfaces, i.e. 109.99.99.96/24 shouldn't be used on the SPOKE side.
As shown in the linked page:

Frontend server:
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre local front-ip remote backend-ip ttl 255
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/30 dev gre1
ip link set gre1 up

Backend server:
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre local backend-ip remote front-ip ttl 255
ip addr add 10.0.0.2/30 dev gre1
ip link set gre1 up


This is symmetric, in that the commands are nearly identical except for the addresses being swapped. So if you already have a netplan configuration on one side:
  tunnels:
    gre1:
      mode: gre
      local: 109.99.99.82       # Local main IP on SPOKE
      remote: 23.20.20.10       # Remote main IP on HUB

It would correspond to the opposite configuration on the other side:
  tunnels:
    gre1:
      mode: gre
      local: 23.20.20.10        # Local main IP on HUB
      remote: 109.99.99.82      # Remote main IP on SPOKE

At this point, if you configure IP addresses on both interfaces (e.g. 10.0.0.1/30 and 10.0.0.2/30 – not 109.99.99.96/24, at least not yet) then both should be able to ping each other. This needs to work – bidirectionally – before continuing:



Hub
Spoke




  tunnels:    gre1:      [...]      addresses:        - 10.0.0.2/30
  tunnels:    gre1:      [...]      addresses:        - 10.0.0.1/30



From there, there are two ways to let HUB use one of SPOKE's addresses:

NAT, which is used in the other post. This method always works, but it will not let you use curl --interface <real_ip> exactly – you have to specify the internal GRE address in the commands, e.g. curl --interface 10.0.0.2 (more-or-less as if SPOKE were a basic home router and HUB were behind its NAT).
The "real" IP address 109.99.99.96 should be configured as a secondary address on SPOKE's Ethernet interface, so that SPOKE would respond to ARP queries for it (see the "on-link" explanation as in the other method, except for this being "regular" ARP and not proxy-ARP).
Alternatively, it might work to configure 109.99.99.96 on gre1 or even lo as Linux will – by default – reply to ARP even for addresses on different interfaces; but some Linux distributions disable that misfeature, so it would be more correct to configure 109.99.99.96 on Ethernet.
Netplan does not manage iptables or nftables rules, so those would still need to be configured externally:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d front-ip -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/30 ! -o gre+ -j SNAT --to-source 109.99.99.96

# plus "filter" rules in case your FORWARD chain is deny-by-default
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.2 -j ACCEPT

After the DNAT and SNAT rules are in place, you need to set up policy routing on HUB so that it would route all traffic – including, most importantly, "reply" packets in response to inbound connections – through the tunnel:
  tunnels:
    gre1:
      [...]
      address:
      - 10.0.0.2/30             # continuing from earlier
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.0.1
        table: 100
      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.0.0.0/30       # match this same interface's address
        table: 100              # on match, use routes from this table

...corresponding to the ip rule commands:
echo '100 GRE' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/30 table GRE
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 table GRE

You can define a named table via /etc/iproute2/rt_tables but it is not required (neither for ip nor Netplan).

Pure routing, which is similar to the configuration you attempted: If the public /24 were routed to SPOKE directly, then the real address that you want HUB to be able to use – 100.99.99.96 – would have to be configured on the HUB end, not on SPOKE. Instead, SPOKE's configuration would need to route that address through the tunnel:



Hub
Spoke




  tunnels:    gre1:      [...]      addresses:        - 109.99.99.96/32
  tunnels:    gre1:      [...]      routes:        - to: 100.99.99.96/32



In this case, the 10.x/30 addresses can be removed. (If you kept them, you can specify via: 10.0.0.2 on SPOKE's route for clarity, as would be needed for actual Ethernet links, but for GRE tunnels it's optional.)
The problem with this method is that most likely, the 109.x/24 is not currently routed to SPOKE but is an "on-link" subnet, meaning that SPOKE needs to still answer ARP queries on its behalf. Linux supports "proxy ARP" as a built-in feature, but unfortunately Netplan does not expose the corresponding networkd setting through YAML, which likely rules out this method. (And unlike in the NAT method, you can't just configure 109.99.99.96 on SPOKE's own interfaces as that would override the route.)
If you choose this method anyway, you'll need a proxy ARP entry on SPOKE:
ip neigh add proxy 100.99.99.96 dev eth0

You will likely still need iptables filter rules in the FORWARD chain to allow traffic on SPOKE, same as in the other method, although this time it needs to match the "real" IP address (as that's what the tunnel will carry when using this method), while the DNAT/SNAT rules are not needed.
iptables -A FORWARD -d 100.99.99.96 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 100.99.99.96 -j ACCEPT

And similar to the other method, you will definitely need the "policy routing" rule on HUB:
  tunnels:
    gre1:
      [...]
      address:
      - 100.99.99.96/32
      routes:
      - to: default
        table: 100
      routing-policy:
      - from: 100.99.99.96/32   # match this same interface's address
        table: 100              # on match, use routes from this table



If the configuration doesn't fully work, install tcpdump and use tcpdump -n -i gre1 on both sides to look at the traffic.

Thanks for the detailed answer, but I was only able to follow you until the mutual ping, which works. After that, it's not clear where the NAT commands are executed, on HUB or SPOKE, I tried either (separated with reboots) and they didn't seem to have the desired effect, or any effect at all. Any luck with getting this to work between two Ubuntu 22.04 servers in the wild?

All of the iptables rules are only needed on SPOKE. Keep in mind -A adds to the end of the list so you need to verify what other rules you already have in PREROUTING and such (use -I instead to insert above conflicting rules, or delete conflicting rules outright, or iptables-save > rules.txt then edit as needed then iptables-restore < rules.txt).

Use tcpdump -n to verify traffic, e.g. ping 8.8.8.8 and run it on SPOKE's gre1 to verify that it receives a ping to 8.8.8.8, then run tcpdump -n -i eth0 icmp on SPOKE's eth0 to verify that it both forwards and NATs the packets. If it doesn't forward the packet at all, that's one problem; if it forwards the packet but doesn't apply SNAT to its source address, that's another; if it forwards the packet with SNAT applied but doesn't receive a reply, that's yet another problem.
